# Query a phone call via ADB commands

Tags: java, android, adb

Is there a way to query a phone call status with ADB commands?

For instance, I want to see if a phone call is still active while in a phone call or if it is not there (has dropped)

Comment: I don't think so....I need to explicitly use ABD commands via command prompt on a PC

Answer (score 6):

You could use `dumpsys` command.

```
$ adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry
```

The field `mCallState` gives the call status:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry | grep "mCallState"
```

1. When in **Idle** mode:

   ```
   $ adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry | grep "mCallState"         
   mCallState=0
   ```
2. When call is **connected**:

   ```
   $ adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry | grep "mCallState"         
   mCallState=2
   ```
3. When an **incoming** call (Phone in ringing mode):

   ```
   $ adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry | grep "mCallState\|mCallIncomingNumber"
   mCallState=1
   mCallIncomingNumber=+9191XXXXXXXX
   ```

More information here:

1. Android [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).
2. TelephonyManager [Call States](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_IDLE).

Tested on `Android v4.4.4`

**Misc**:
You can get a lot of information using `dumpsys`.
To see what parameters dumpsys support use `adb shell dumpsys | grep "DUMP OF SERVICE"`.

Comment: Very useful information! Note that if you have dual-sim phone you will get two states - one for each SIM slot.