# Android emergency calls testing

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests, phone-call

Is there a way to make emergency calls without using the android GUI, from command line/script/service and indicating whether the call was established successfully?

Comment: this might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897758/query-a-phone-call-via-adb-commands

Comment: "adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED -d tel:911"
solved it.